# PayPal Adaptive Parallel Payments

Tags: paypal, parallel-processing, split

Ok here goes:

**Hypothetical:** Let's say I'm selling digital content online for various freelance artists. The artists submit thier content to my site and I make them available to the public for a fee.

A customer enters the site to buy access to the content. Once the customer pays thru PayPal the payment is automatically split between my business (reciever 1) and the artist (reciever 2) through the use of Parallel Adaptive Payments.

**Question:** Is it possible to assign some type of "artist ID" to each submitted content that links that artist's content to thier PayPal account so that they are secured payment for each sale while still maintaining payment to the business from each split payment transaction? Keep in mind there will be multiple artists with each artist submitting multiple pieces of content.

I hope I didn't make this more complicated than what it is but if anyone can help with this it would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I completely understand your question.  However, you could pass over a an id in one of the available variables such as item id, custom or etc.  If you are trying to get some type of identifier back on your end.